# tailwind css showing warnings about generated css file missing styles

Tags: css, tailwind-css, tailwind-in-js, tailwind-ui, tailwind-3

This is my first time installing and running tailwind CSS. I follow the instructions and did everything accordingly but then it started showing some warnings like below

[image]

Can you tell me why I am getting these warnings and anyway for me to fix them? As I am worried that my generated CSS will be missing styles So help is needed to fix it

Also, can I keep the tailwind CSS in watch mode? Please give me the command line or video or explain to me the way to fix it? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Make sure you don't have repeated properties in your Tailwind config file. After upgrading from v2 to v3, Accidently I had put two content properties. Other than that make sure you have done migration properly.

framework guide: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/framework-guides

upgrade guide: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/upgrade-guide

Answer (score 1):

This warning occurred because you did not use any of the tailwind classes, causing tailwind to suspect that the project config was not implemented correctly.

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation

Answer (score 0):

It's look like you dont have the tailwind config file. Take a look in your root folder if you have. If not you can create one by this command: `npx tailwindcss init`

Then the tailwind cli will create the `tailwind.config.js` file. It looks like:

```js
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation